# Сумма и среднее арифметическое положительных чисел в последовательности

Tags: c

Никак не могу решить.
На обработку поступает последовательность из шести целых чисел (0 не вводится). Нужно написать программу, которая выводит на экран сумму и среднее арифметическое всех положительных чисел в исходной последовательности. Программист написал программу неправильно.

```
#include '' stdafx.h'' 

# include '' conio.h'' 

{ int i, x, sum; 

  double cred; 

  sum = 1; 

   for (i = 1;  i < 6;  i++) 

     { scanf( "%d", &x); 

        if (x > 0) 

           {sum = sum + i; } } 

   cred = sum / 6; 

   printf("%d\n", sum); 

   printf("%d\n", cred);    

getch(); return 0;}
```

Comment: *Программист написал программу неправильно.* Это фраза из текста задания? или это знакомый программист решил, но через задницу?

Comment: Это фраза из текста задания

Comment: Ааа... ну тогда ищите. На 2 ошибки в ответах и комментариях указания есть, на как минимум ещё две (а, может, и больше) - нет.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужно не работающая программа, а показать все ошибки? Типа, анализ кода? Их тут с десяток, не меньше... Начиная от странных кавычек в `#include`...

Answer (score 0):

не  sum = sum + i;
а sum = sum + x;

Comment: Этого мало. Есть ещё одна ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

При условии отсутствия переполнения в сумме:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int i_pos = 0, x, sum;

    double cred;

    sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if (x > 0) {
            i_pos += 1;
            sum = sum + x;
        }
    }

    cred = (double) sum / i_pos;

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    printf("%lf\n", cred);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарий к ответу Артём Артёмыча на 100% подходит и к этому ответу.

Comment: @КириллКабаков если ответ устроил, примите его, поставив галочку под количеством голосов

Comment: среднее арифметическое положительных чисел неправильно выдаст. Сумму положительных делите на  общее количество

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin согласен, исправил